# setInterval only working inside of if(){} block

Tags: javascript, if-statement, scope, setinterval

So I think there is something key to be picked up from this situation I encountered and was hoping some experience could explain it.

When I run this code, it does NOT work:

```
t5 = "nikolas"+t4;

setInterval(adds,250);

function adds(){
    if (t4 < 100){
        t4=t4+1;
    }    
    else{
        return;
    }
};
```

this does DOES work:

```
t5 = "nikolas"+t4;

adds(t4);

function adds(a){

    if (a < 100){
        a=a+1;
        setInterval(t4=a,250);
    }

    else{
        return;
    }
};
```

TL;DR: setInterval seems to work inside the if block but not outside. When it works it displays nikolast4 where t4 is an integer that 'ticks' from 1-100 (eg.**strong text** nikolas0 nikolas1 nikolas2 nikolas3 nikolas4)

Also this code (due to the application I am programming in) is supposed to refresh every 250ms (but take the whole refreshing part with a grain of salt, not totally 100% sure about that).

Comment: Please provide an example at [jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net), these codes seem not to display anything.

Comment: `t4=a` isn't being run as an interval. `setInterval` expects a *function*. You're assigning the value of `a` to `t4` and then passing the result of that assignment operation to `setInterval`. Perhaps you mean to do `setInterval(function() { t4=a },250);`

Comment: add `var t4;` to the beginning of your first example and see what happens.

Comment: @apsillers A strange thing here is, that OP says that's the code which _is working_.

Comment: @Cobra_Fast t4 is already declared in the program that will be running this code. and like I said the bottom example works fine.

Comment: @apsillers but the bottom does work and it does observe the 250ms timeout.

Comment: the only reason it could work is if the whole code quoted in the question is itself called by a setInterval. Because setting TimeInterval with a number (=a) as function argument will just silently fail. In this case, t5 = "nikolas"+t4; t4++; can replace the whole code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below is fully functionnal, and looks very much like your non-working example.

You can check here : 
http://jsbin.com/ofezip/1/edit

So i guess you have an issue with the scope of your variables.

```
window.onload = function()  {

   var myOutput = document.createElement("output"); 
   document.body.appendChild(myOutput);

   var t4 = 0;

   var helloInterval = setInterval(adds,250);

   function adds(){
          if (t4 < 10){
              t4++;
              myOutput.value = "hello " + t4;
          }    
          else {
              myOutput.value = "goodbye" ;
              clearInterval(helloInterval);      
              return;
        }
   }

};
```